# How to render an epub file in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hi i was searching for a package for rendering an epub file in react native and also i found [this](http://%20https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn)

but i surly believe this package is not managing and developing anymore

so do you know another way to render an epub file in react-native ?

Comment: Last commit from that package is "only" 21 days ago. I wouldn't say that it has been left by his contributors yet

Comment: @auticcat It is not compatible with the latest version of the react native and it is not answering any issue . But there must be another way to do this job surely

Answer (score 2):

one way you can use open epub with webview , thats a little complicate ,

but another way use some epubjs-rn packge , check package , some resource of it is different and updater than **futurepress/epubjs-rn** ,

I Use **@ottofeller/epubjs-rn** , that compatible with react-native **0.62.2**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `epubjs-rn`

**Example**

```js
import { Epub } from 'epubjs-rn';
...
<Epub src={"https://s3.amazonaws.com/epubjs/books/moby-dick/OPS/package.opf"}
          flow={"paginated"} />
```

[Official `epubjs-rn` github homepage](https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn)

Comment: Did you see the link i attached to my question ? It is exactly what you've said .  Unfortunately it depreciated  .

Comment: Really? I could not see the homepage of the attached link.

Comment: No problem . Thanks for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to render Epub in react native app
then  I got mainly packages like
epubjs
epub-rn
and a lot number of copies of both on them but any on them is not working with our latest code
then I got the working package for epub rendering into react-native name
[epubjs-rn-62](https://www.npmjs.com/package/epubjs-rn-62)

to install it run the command

> npm i epubjs-rn-62

it's working fine with 62,63 and more version of react

also no need to link in the current version of react native

**usage**

```
   import { Epub } from 'epubjs-rn';
Then you can add the reader element in your code:

<Epub src={"https://s3.amazonaws.com/epubjs/books/moby-dick/OPS/package.opf"}
          flow={"paginated"} />
```

to use with streamer

```
import { Epub, Streamer } from "epubjs-rn";
let streamer = new Streamer();

streamer.start("8899")
    .then((origin) => {
        console.log("Served from:", origin)
        return this.streamer.get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/epubjs/books/moby-dick.epub");
    })
    .then((src) => {
        console.log("Loading from:", src);
        return this.setState({src});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no epub-creator in react-native so I created one [react-native-epub-creator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-epub-creator) check it out and let me know